# Use of apostrophe and "of" in same sentence to form possesssive

Tags: grammar, phrase-usage

To form possessive constructions with adjectives and pronouns, the rules are unambiguous:
e.g. "My (adj) daughter" and "daughter of mine (possessive pronoun)" are both standard usage.  However, when the "owner" happens to be a proper noun, usage gets slightly murkier. The use of an apostrophe in the case of "John's daughter" is standard English; however, in the periphrastic case, I have encountered both in common speech and in writing something like, "**daughter of John**" and "**daughter of John's**," the latter in which both an apostrophe and the preposition "of" are used.  What is the rule here?

Answer (score 1):

The double possessive, or double genitive, dates back to Chaucer's time, and mostly gets used without being remarked upon by native speakers. If you want a 'rule' then let that be that the double possessive is only used for people and animals, and you use 'of'. You can say *a daughter of John's*, but never *a leg of the table's*. The usage is not restricted to proper nouns: you can say *a friend of my sister's* or *a servant of the king's*.

Sometimes a double possessive is useful to avoid abiguity - consider *a dream of Mary* and *a dream of Mary's*.

You will find pedants and stylists who object to the double possessive, but, as I wrote above, it has been present in English since the 14th century, and does not give native speakers any trouble.

[Double possessives demonstrate the power of ‘of’](https://www.latimes.com/socal/burbank-leader/opinion/tn-blr-me-aword-20180719-story.html)

[A guide to double possessives](https://www.merriam-webster.com/words-at-play/double-possessives-genitives)